# Extract weather data from dictionary - spotfire

Tags: python, ironpython, spotfire

I want to get weather data in spotfire as a html data table. Spotfire does provide Ironpython support but not the flexibility to add our own modules. So being a shorthand here. Using iframe and src as api doesnt help in this case.

My Script:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
clr.AddReference('System.Web.Extensions')
import System
from System import DateTime
from System.Data import DataSet, DataTable
from System.IO import StreamReader, StreamWriter, MemoryStream, SeekOrigin
from System.Net import HttpWebRequest
from System.Web.Script.Serialization import JavaScriptSerializer
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataType, DataTableSaveSettings
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import import TextFileDataSource, TextDataReaderSettings


#uri = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=ec0313a918fa729d4372555ada5fb1f8"
uri = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=524901,703448,2643743&units=metric&appid=ec0313a918fa729d4372555ada5fb1f8"
webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
response = webRequest.GetResponse()
streamReader = StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
jsonData = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
js = JavaScriptSerializer()
dataDict = js.Deserialize(jsonData, object)

print dataDict

# Close the connection
response.Close()
```

I need to extract some common values for multiple cities like: Name, Id, Description, temperature from the dictionary dataDict.

I am hitting a stone here.

It would be great if you can help me/ guide me on how to get these values from this complex dictionary.

Example dataDict: `Dictionary[str, object]({'cnt' : 3, 'list' : Array[object]((Dictionary[str, object]({'coord' : Dictionary[str, object]({'lon' : <System.Decimal object at 0x0000000000000055 [37.62]>, 'lat' : <System.Decimal object at 0x0000000000000056 [55.75]>}), 'sys' : Dictionary[str, object]({'type' : 1, 'id' : 7323, 'message' : <System.Decimal object at 0x0000000000000057 [0.2107]>, 'country' : 'RU', 'sunrise' : 1484372967, 'sunset' : 1484400490}), 'weather' : Array[object]((Dictionary[str, object]({'id' : 802, 'main' : 'Clouds', 'description' : 'scattered clouds', 'icon' : '03d'}))), 'main' : Dictionary[str, object]({'temp' : <System.Decimal object at 0x0000000000000058 [-1.5]>, 'pressure' : 1009, 'humidity' : 80, 'temp_min' : -2, 'temp_max' : -1}), 'visibility' : 10000, 'wind' : Dictionary[str, object]({'speed' : 6, 'deg' : 160, 'gust' : 12}), 'clouds' : Dictionary[str, object]({'all' : 40}), 'dt' : 1484398800, 'id' : 524901, 'name' : 'Moscow'}), Dictionary[str, object]({'coord' : Dictionary[str, object]({'lon' : <System.Decimal object at 0x0000000000000059 [30.52]>, 'lat' : <System.Decimal object at 0x000000000000005A [50.43]>}), 'sys' : Dictionary[str, object]({'type' : 1, 'id' : 7358, 'message' : <System.Decimal object at 0x000000000000005B [0.1886]>, 'country' : 'UA', 'sunrise' : 1484373141, 'sunset' : 1484403724}), 'weather' : Array[object]((Dictionary[str, object]({'id' : 804, 'main' : 'Clouds', 'description' : 'overcast clouds', 'icon' : '04d'}))), 'main' : Dictionary[str, object]({'temp' : 3, 'pressure' : 998, 'humidity' : 86, 'temp_min' : 3, 'temp_max' : 3}), 'visibility' : 10000, 'wind' : Dictionary[str, object]({'speed' : 4, 'deg' : 170, 'var_beg' : 100, 'var_end' : 210}), 'clouds' : Dictionary[str, object]({'all' : 90}), 'dt' : 1484398800, 'id' : 703448, 'name' : 'Kiev'}), Dictionary[str, object]({'coord' : Dictionary[str, object]({'lon' : <System.Decimal object at 0x000000000000005C [-0.13]>, 'lat' : <System.Decimal object at 0x000000000000005D [51.51]>}), 'sys' : Dictionary[str, object]({'type' : 1, 'id' : 5091, 'message' : <System.Decimal object at 0x000000000000005E [0.1699]>, 'country' : 'GB', 'sunrise' : 1484380764, 'sunset' : 1484410813}), 'weather' : Array[object]((Dictionary[str, object]({'id' : 501, 'main' : 'Rain', 'description' : 'moderate rain', 'icon' : '10d'}))), 'main' : Dictionary[str, object]({'temp' : <System.Decimal object at 0x000000000000005F [4.01]>, 'pressure' : 1020, 'humidity' : 80, 'temp_min' : 2, 'temp_max' : 6}), 'visibility' : 10000, 'wind' : Dictionary[str, object]({'speed' : <System.Decimal object at 0x0000000000000060 [5.7]>, 'deg' : 290}), 'clouds' : Dictionary[str, object]({'all' : 20}), 'dt' : 1484400000, 'id' : 2643743, 'name' : 'London'})))})`

Comment: "I need to [*do xx*] ... I am hitting a stone [wall] here." is a bit unclear. You described what you did so far (which is good!) but what is your actual question? Extracting certain data out of a JSON (I presume) object?

Comment: Your example dataDict isn't valid JSON or a Python data structure like a `dict` or a `list`. Please [edit] your question and supply it in one of those two forms.

Comment: Yes Red, I want some data to be shown, however I  boiled it down to :

print dataDict["list"] #<pass array or object>

and I am thinking to put it in a loop for len(dataDict["list"])-1 to get dynamic values. Unless you have a better suggestion/solution :)